# The use of the word "this" instead of "that" in context

Tags: word-choice

Tell me please if it grammatical and natural to use *this* in the following context.

> [John] Kate, could make sandwiches for the whole family please?
>
> [Kate] Sure, I am happy to do **this**.

If is correct, then would be there any difference in the sentence meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [John] Kate, could **you** make sandwiches for the whole family please?

Kate needs addressing directly.

> [Kate] Sure, I am happy to do this.

The construction is fine as it stands, though I doubt any native would get past just "Sure"
If they did, I'd think they would be more likely to say

> Sure, I'd be happy to do **that**

'I would be' indicating the task isn't yet started, which pushes 'this' towards 'that'... at a distance, measured in time rather than metres.
"I'm happy to do this" more implies they are currently making the sandwiches.